# Generated play json implicit instances cause StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-macros, play-json

I have the following code:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
object Test {
   sealed trait T
   case class A(s: String) extends T

   implicit val writesA: OWrites[A] = Json.writes[A]
   implicit val writesT: OWrites[T] = Json.writes[T]

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val x = A("str")
      println(Json.toJson[T](x)(writesT))
   }
}
```

It causes a `StackOverflowError` when run.

If I add `lazy` in front of `writesT`, the `StackOverflowError` goes away and everything works:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
object Test {
   sealed trait T
   case class A(s: String) extends T

   implicit val writesA: OWrites[A] = Json.writes[A]
   implicit lazy val writesT: OWrites[T] = Json.writes[T]

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val x = A("str")
      println(Json.toJson[T](x)(writesT))
   }
}
```

The `StackOverflowError` also disappears when I move the `implicit`s into the `main` function:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
object Test {
   sealed trait T
   case class A(s: String) extends T

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      implicit val writesA: OWrites[A] = Json.writes[A]
      implicit val writesT: OWrites[T] = Json.writes[T]
      val x = A("str")
      println(Json.toJson[T](x)(writesT))
   }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why I get a `StackOverflowError` in the first case?

My suspicion is that it has something to do with initialization orders and the macros that play-json uses in the background. But if that is the case I don't get why using `lazy` helps, because the code should still be generated at compile time and simply evaluating it later at runtime shouldn't change anything. Apparently in the later cases the `writesA` instance is found by `writesT` but not in the first case. Why does adding `lazy` resolve a compile-time issue with the resolution of implicits and macro code generation?

Or is this an issue on a completely different level?

I am using Scala 2.12.3 and play-json 2.6.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working just fine with Play JSON 2.7.x

```
import play.api.libs.json._

sealed trait T
case class A(s: String) extends T

implicit val writesA: OWrites[A] = Json.writes[A]
implicit val writesT: OWrites[T] = Json.writes[T]

val x = A("str")
println(Json.toJson[T](x)(writesT))

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

scala> println(Json.toJson[T](x)(writesT))
                                   ^
{"s":"str","_type":"$line2.$read.$iw.$iw.A"}
```

Guess it's related to the ["blight of contravariant" on `Writes` implicit](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/pull/216) fixed since.

Workaround for Play JSON 2.6 is to implement the `Writes` (or `OFormat`) instance for the sealed trait manually.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import play.api.libs.json._

sealed trait T
case class A(s: String) extends T

implicit val writesT: OWrites[T] = {
  val writesA: OWrites[A] = Json.writes[A]

  OWrites[T] {
    case t: A => writesA.writes(t) + ("_type" -> Json.toJson("A"))
    case _ => ???
  }
}

val x = A("str")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import play.api.libs.json._
defined trait T
defined class A
writesT: play.api.libs.json.OWrites[T] = play.api.libs.json.OWrites$$anon$3@69a03da1
x: A = A(str)

scala> println(Json.toJson[T](x)(writesT))
{"s":"str","_type":"A"}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixes the issue for me. Though I don't get why the `lazy` or the more local scope also work around the issue.